# Why does angular's dependency injection need private or public to work?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, scope, angular-services

I have noticed that an angular class doesn't recognize an injected service if it hasn't been injected with explicit scope definition.

This following code doesn't work

```
constructor(router: Router) {}
```

but this one does.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Can anyone explain why? I believe that if you don't explicitly write the property's scope definition, then it is public by default, like classes properties, but seems like is not the case in here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever you define in your constructor is taken as a parameter. It is a `TypeScript` convenience that you can attach an accessor to it. For instance:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

is a shorthand for ES6:

```
constructor(router) {
  this.router = router;
}
```

Dependency injection still works though, if you do the following:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
  // router only available in this scope
}
```

It's just that it's only available inside the constructor, and not in the class instance, because it's inside the constructor `{}` scope. A class field is defined in the class `{}` scope, and therefore accessible in the entire class

Answer (score 1):

The first is just a parameter. The second is a parameter that *also* declares and sets a private field. (`public router: Router` would be a parameter that *also* declares and sets a public field.) DI expects that the instance will retain the thing being injected on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

using a private variable in the constructor parameter in Angular is a convention that promotes encapsulation, leverages TypeScript's automatic property initialization, and aligns with Angular's dependency injection system. It contributes to a cleaner and more maintainable codebase.